# print out all filenames within directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I want to list all files within a directory so i did :

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(mypath):
    print(filenames)
```

why do we use three variables not just filenames variable ? thanks

Comment: Do you have an inkling about what the other variables can tell you?

Comment: What about having a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk ?

Comment: parent path, children directories and children files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` returns a generator, that creates a tuple of values (current_path, directories in current_path, files in current_path), therefore we use 3 variables in the loop to unpack these.

Every time the generator is called it will follow each directory recursively until no further sub-directories are available from the initial directory that walk was called upon.

You can check out these python docs for os.walk:
[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)